# rundeck pass output from job(step) one to job(step) two

Tags: rundeck

In rundeck, I have two selections, selection1 and selection2 which will be executed on node1 and node2 respectively. Slection2 's input is from output of selections. How can I make it ? with two jobs or two steps? and How to pass the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass options between jobs using [Job Reference Step](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/node-steps/builtin.html#job-reference-step) and [arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TShQw.jpg). I leave an example with two jobs: JobA and JobB, the JobA just print an option and the JobB that call the JobA and pass their option to JobA option through argument.

Job A:

```xml
<joblist>
    <job>
        <context>
            <options preserveOrder="true">
                <option name="opta" />
            </options>
        </context>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description />
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>6d64bd33-71de-4d20-8bcd-c65785603b23</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobA</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing="false" strategy="node-first">
            <command>
                <exec>echo ${option.opta}</exec>
            </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>6d64bd33-71de-4d20-8bcd-c65785603b23</uuid>
    </job>
</joblist>
```

Job B:

```xml
<joblist>
    <job>
        <context>
            <options preserveOrder="true">
                <option name="optb" />
            </options>
        </context>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description />
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>22d0e6cc-e0f3-48e5-b8a5-3007e448ae18</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobB</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing="false" strategy="node-first">
            <command>
                <jobref name="JobA" nodeStep="true">
                    <arg line="-opta ${option.optb}" />
                    <uuid>6d64bd33-71de-4d20-8bcd-c65785603b23</uuid>
                </jobref>
            </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>22d0e6cc-e0f3-48e5-b8a5-3007e448ae18</uuid>
    </job>
</joblist>
```

Also, you can capture some output and pass this data using arguments between jobs. I leave another Example:

Job A (just print an option):

```xml
<joblist>
    <job>
        <context>
            <options preserveOrder="true">
                <option name="opta" />
            </options>
        </context>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description />
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>6d64bd33-71de-4d20-8bcd-c65785603b23</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>JobA</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing="false" strategy="node-first">
            <command>
                <exec>echo ${option.opta}</exec>
            </command>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>6d64bd33-71de-4d20-8bcd-c65785603b23</uuid>
    </job>
</joblist>
```

Job B (it generates data, store at `${data.USER}` variable and call the JobA to pass that variable as an argument using Job Reference Step):

```xml
<joblist>
    <job>
        <defaultTab>nodes</defaultTab>
        <description>Regex and data passing demo.</description>
        <executionEnabled>true</executionEnabled>
        <id>a0daf1e3-e918-43dc-b232-bc46a7a287b6</id>
        <loglevel>INFO</loglevel>
        <name>Regex</name>
        <nodeFilterEditable>false</nodeFilterEditable>
        <scheduleEnabled>true</scheduleEnabled>
        <sequence keepgoing="false" strategy="node-first">
            <command>
                <exec>env</exec>
            </command>
            <command>
                <jobref name="JobA" nodeStep="true">
                    <arg line="-opta ${data.USER}" />
                    <uuid>6d64bd33-71de-4d20-8bcd-c65785603b23</uuid>
                </jobref>
            </command>
            <pluginConfig>
                <LogFilter type="key-value-data">
                    <config>
                        <logData>true</logData>
                        <regex>^(USER)\s*=\s*(.+)$</regex>
                    </config>
                </LogFilter>
            </pluginConfig>
        </sequence>
        <uuid>a0daf1e3-e918-43dc-b232-bc46a7a287b6</uuid>
    </job>
</joblist>
```

You can see a very useful example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ao2SvpspWl4).